# While loop test case help needed

Tags: python, while-loop

can you help me this problem. I am stuck with test case 1 and 2.

```
def upper_1():
    countCap = 0
    while True:
        word = input('Enter word or press Enter/Return key: ')
        if word == '':
            print("'0 words were entered'")
            break
        else:
            if word[0].isupper():
                countCap += 1
            
    if word != '':
        print('Words with first letter in upper case = ', str(countCap))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some logical errors in your code. Some minor fixes will do:

```
def upper_1():
    countCap = 0
    words = False
    while True:
        word = input('Enter word or press Enter/Return key: ')
        if word == '':
            break  # always the end of the loop, even if words were entered
        words = True
        if word[0].isupper():
            countCap += 1
            
    if words:  # this is where you can check
        print('Words with first letter in upper case = ', str(countCap))
    else:
        print("0 words were entered")
```

Or a bit shortened:

```
def upper_1():
    countCap = words = 0  # [== False]
    while True:
        if not (word := input('Enter word or press Enter/Return key: ')):
            break
        words = True
        countCap += word[0].isupper()
            
    if words:
        print('Words with first letter in upper case = ', str(countCap))
    else:
        print("0 words were entered")
```